Excel formula excluding duplicate values
I am hoping to write a formula in Excel that counts the number of Functions that have a value in Column C without repeating the title in Column A. The list works like this:
Column A is an overarching job title. Column B is the level of that job title. Some levels do not have hours associated with an overarching job title. So Engineer Senior could have 10 hours but Engineer Junior could have zero. And if Engineer Senior and Engineer Junior BOTH have hours, I only want the formula to count Engineer as ONE count. Not two. I want to collect the number of Job Functions that have hours associated.
Any ideas? I may be overthinking this. So, once Engineer (at ANY level) is counted (Column C > 0), then the formula can skip the next occurrence of engineer, with or without hours associated.
]

In Excel 2016, the easiest way to achieve this is to add an additional column that lists the overarching job title in each row, e.g. Engineer, Manager, Analyst, etc.
Then you can build a pivot table to summarize the data by job title and level.

There is a lot of other data on this sheet and this workbook is quite large, I want to avoid adding any helper columns.

It may be that you need to edit your ask to be clearer as it seems to me that pivot tables should be the answer. I don't there is a need to add a helper column. Rows is column A (Functions) and Vaues is Column C (Total FY25). You can change the aggregation to Max, but it shouldn't matter. Just apply a filter to the pivot table to remove rows with -0- values.
